# Microservice architecture communication with rabbitmq message broker

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices

I have started to develop an ecommerce application using a microservices architecture. Every microservice will have a separate database. For now, I know I want to use a Node.js microservice to handle products and also serve as a search engine for them. I plan on having a Ruby on Rails server-microservice that should handle all the requests and then if the request is not meant to be processed by it, (e.g. the request is to add a new product) to send this information somehow using RabbitMQ to the Node.js microservice, and let it perform the action. Is this an acceptable architectural design or I'm completely off route?

Answer (score 0):

> Ruby on Rails server-microservice that should handle all the requests (You can do better)

A. For this, what you need is an Reverse Proxy.

- A reverse proxy is able to forward each incoming request to the microservice that's responsible for processing it.
- It can also act as a Load Balancer : it'll distribute the incoming requests accross many services (if, for instance, you want to deploy multiple instances of the same service)
- ...

B. You will also need an API Gateway for managing Authentication & Authorization, and handling Security, Traceability, Logging, ... of the requests.

For (A) & (B), you can you use either [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) or [Kong](https://konghq.com/)

Use RabbitMQ in case you want to establish Event-based and/or Asynchronous communication among your microservices. Here's a simple example : Everytime a user confirms an Order, OrderService informs ProductService to update the quantity of the product that's been ordered.

The advantage of using RabbitMQ here is that OrderService won't stay on a blocking state while waiting for ProductService to let him know whether he received the info or not, or he updated the quantity or not ... he'll move on and handle the other incoming requests.